# Next Months PHP Calendar

Tags: php, calendar

I have a web page where I am putting 4 simple calendars which show the dates for the next 4 months. I have got the code for showing the current month but I'm unsure of how to edit the code to show the second, third and fourth months. Here is the code that I am using to find the current month:

```
<table>
<?php
$today = date("d"); // Current day
$month = date("m"); // Current month
$year = date("Y"); // Current year
$days = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,$month,$year); // Days in current month

$lastmonth = date("t", mktime(0,0,0,$month-1,1,$year)); // Days in previous month

$start = date("N", mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year)); // Starting day of current month
$finish = date("N", mktime(0,0,0,$month,$days,$year)); // Finishing day of  current month
$laststart = $start - 1; // Days of previous month in calander

$counter = 1;
$nextMonthCounter = 1;

if($start > 5){ $rows = 6; }else {$rows = 5; }
for($i = 1; $i <= $rows; $i++){
    echo '<tr class="week">';
    for($x = 1; $x <= 7; $x++){             

        if(($counter - $start) < 0){
            $date = (($lastmonth - $laststart) + $counter);
            $class = 'class="blur"';
        }else if(($counter - $start) >= $days){
            $date = ($nextMonthCounter);
            $nextMonthCounter++;

            $class = 'class="blur"';

        }else {
            $date = ($counter - $start + 1);
            if($today == $counter - $start + 1){
                $class = 'class="today"';
            }
        }


        echo '<td '.$class.'><a class="date">'. $date . '</a></td>';

        $counter++;
        $class = '';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
?>
</table>
```

What variables do I need to change to make this work for future months?

Comment: You have to understand that code or at least try to understand. You can also pay someone to change it.

Comment: @ElonThan I do understand it to a point. I know htere's something simple like changing a few variables to having month+1 or something like that, but I just can't see exactly where it is and there aren't many tutorials online

Answer (score 1):

To get next month, you have to just change `$month` variable, eg. like this `date("m", strtotime('+1 month'));`

Comment: Thanks, it's strtotime() but I get the idea. The only problem is with the year. I have doen it for 4 months but obviously January is showing up again for 2013, how do I calculate that it's the next year automatically?

Comment: Get current date and extract year from it, `date('Y', strtotime($date))` Then compare to current year.

Comment: Thanks but I used this method in the end: `$year = date("Y", strtotime("+1 months"));` - Seems to be working fine